# What does “ounce-counting” mean?

Tags: meaning, terminology

The product description of a titanium flask reads,

> Appeals to anyone from the ounce-counting mountaineer to the snobby Scotch collector

What does "ounce-counting" mean here? I searched dictionaries but couldn't find a relevant result.

Answer (score 7):

***Ounce counting*** is outdoor-enthusiast jargon for ***minimising the weight of equipment***. Heavy equipment wears out its wearer, so some backpackers, hunters, mountaineers, etc. pay a great deal of attention to how much external weight they carry. They are referred to as *ounce-counting* backpackers, hunters, mountaineers, etc.

> Over the years I have touched on ounce counting when backpack hunting and how I’ve developed a system to help me drop significant pounds (not just ounces, but pounds) from my “going in” pack weight.
>
> — [Eastmans' Issue 156 - OCD (Ounce Counting Document) Packing](https://www.eastmans.com/post/issue-156-ocd-ounce-counting-document-packing)

Marketers use the term as an adjective to attract their target audience of serious adventurers:

> If you are the type of ounce-counting backpacker who hasn't been able to justify carrying a pillow in your pack the ergonomic Exped Air Pillow UL may change your mind.
>
> — [Exped AirPillow UL (2020)](https://www.enwild.com/exped-airpillow-ul-2020.html)